# Extracting string from logfile with regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, logging, awk

I have Home Assistant logfile and I need to extract specific information from it by script in bash.

Log look like this:

```
2017-09-26 20:54:09 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.player1=playing; media_duration=6054, is_volume_muted=False, media_season=-1, media_episode=-1, media_series_title=, media_content_type=movie, media_album_name=, friendly_name=player1, media_title=My movie, supported_features=55231, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.player1?token=5ce13d0e4d8ed86b3073a795a4bd82627b387cf2b6c5dfdc8c64ab9b62ec7d61&cache=f4a48, media_content_id=unknown=tt0266543, volume_level=0.91 @ 2017-09-26T20:44:37.080005+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.player1=playing; media_duration=6054, is_volume_muted=False, media_season=-1, media_episode=-1, media_series_title=, media_content_type=movie, media_album_name=, friendly_name=player1, media_title=My movie, supported_features=55231, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.player1?token=5ce13d0e4d8ed86b3073a795a4bd82627b387cf2b6c5dfdc8c64ab9b62ec7d61&cache=23108, media_content_id=unknown=tt0266543, volume_level=0.91 @ 2017-09-26T20:44:37.080005+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.player1>
2017-09-26 21:30:22 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:22.660153+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; supported_features=21437, is_volume_muted=False, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:22.557344+02:00, app_id=233637DE, friendly_name=player2, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, app_name=YouTube, media_position=0, volume_level=1.0 @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.tv_player2>
2017-09-26 21:30:22 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:22.695325+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:22.660153+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.tv_player2>
2017-09-26 21:30:29 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; media_duration=1789.213605442177, is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:29.115053+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:22.695325+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.tv_player2>
2017-09-26 21:30:29 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; media_duration=1789.213605442177, is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0.733, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:29.843295+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; media_duration=1789.213605442177, is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:29.115053+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.tv_player2>
2017-09-26 21:31:34 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; media_duration=1789.213605442177, is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=65.681, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:31:34.823855+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.tv_player2=playing; media_duration=1789.213605442177, is_volume_muted=False, app_id=233637DE, app_name=YouTube, volume_level=1.0, friendly_name=player2, media_position=0.733, supported_features=21437, media_position_updated_at=2017-09-26T21:30:29.843295+02:00, entity_picture=/api/media_player_proxy/media_player.tv_player2?token=f03173d412f3c7396762605a4f347b83f651d4c0f23935c8b1fccd9305698ffe&cache=88a6b, media_content_id=AcADAFAD, media_title=YT test movie @ 2017-09-26T21:30:21.848088+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.tv_player2>
2017-09-26 22:45:58 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.player1=playing; media_duration=0, is_volume_muted=False, media_album_name=, media_content_type=music, friendly_name=player1, volume_level=0.75, supported_features=55231, media_title=My radio R1 @ 2017-09-26T22:44:57.441924+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.player1=playing; media_duration=0, is_volume_muted=False, media_album_name=, media_content_type=music, friendly_name=player1, volume_level=0.75, supported_features=55231, media_title= @ 2017-09-26T22:44:57.441924+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.player1>
2017-09-26 22:46:09 INFO (MainThread) [homeassistant.core] Bus:Handling <Event state_changed[L]: new_state=<state media_player.player1=playing; media_duration=0, is_volume_muted=False, media_album_name=, media_content_type=music, friendly_name=player1, volume_level=0.75, supported_features=55231, media_title= @ 2017-09-26T22:44:57.441924+02:00>, old_state=<state media_player.player1=playing; media_duration=0, is_volume_muted=False, media_album_name=, media_content_type=music, friendly_name=player1, volume_level=0.75, supported_features=55231, media_title=My radio R1 @ 2017-09-26T22:44:57.441924+02:00>, entity_id=media_player.player1>
```

And I need to extract by script info about: **time** (first occured), **friendly_name** and **media_title** without duplicites in *media_title*.

something like this in output file:

```
2017-09-26 20:54:09, player1, My movie
2017-09-26 21:30:22, player2, YT test movie
2017-09-26 22:45:58, player1, My radio R1
```

I tried grep, sed and without propper result.
Thank you

Comment: Match `([-\d: ]+) INFO.*friendly_name=([\w ]+).*media_title=([\w ]+).*` and replace with `\1, \2, \3` https://regex101.com/r/sM1AOj/1

Comment: Please share what you tried, so that we can help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **awk** solution:

```
awk '{ 
         d=$1" "$2; 
         match($0,/friendly_name=([^,]+).*media_title=([^[:space:]][^@,]+)[[:space:]]*[@,]/,a);
         if (a[1]!="" && a[2]!="" && !(a[1]"@"a[2] in res)) { 
             res[a[1]"@"a[2]]; 
             print d,a[1],a[2] 
         } 
     }' OFS=', ' logfile
```

The output:

```
2017-09-26 20:54:09, player1, My movie
2017-09-26 21:30:22, player2, YT test movie 
2017-09-26 22:45:58, player1, My radio R1
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU **awk** solution. Since we don't know in what order `friendly_name` and `media_title` occur we need to split up the matches:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/friendly_name=([^,]+)/,a) && 
       match($0,/media_title=([^,@]+?)(\s@)?/,b) && 
       a[1] && b[1] && !(b[1] in arr){
           arr[b[1]]; 
           printf "%s, %s, %s\n", $1" "$2, a[1], b[1]}' file
```

which gives as result:

```
2017-09-26 20:54:09, player1, My movie
2017-09-26 21:30:22, player2, YT test movie
2017-09-26 22:45:58, player1, My radio R1
```

Comment: Good approach. You can change `&& !(b[1] in arr){
           arr[b[1]];` to `&& !arr[a[1]b[1]]++ { printf .... `

Comment: @batMan Then we're reading the question differently. My answer shows *the first time a  media title gets accessed*, while yours answers *the first time user A accesses a media title*. Not sure what OP wants. With current input output is the same.

Comment: @batMan Ow. Rereading the question: *media_title without duplicites in media_title* seems to point in my direction.